# How to call a REST function from the services.js?

Tags: javascript, rest

I got a REST function like this:

```
@Override
public String getNameForMW() {
    String MW_Url = props.getProperty("MW_Url"); //<<this returns a String
    return MW_Url.split("/")[3].toString();
}
```

Then I have an interface:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/getNameForMW")
public String getNameForMW();
```

Then I have the services.js file, where my factory is located, and there is this line:

```
var pathForMW = $http.get(path + 'getNameForMW');
```

but the outcome is not a string but an object like this:
[image]

can u help me?

I need it to be a simple string, that I reed from the properties file

Comment: And this is… Angular…? You are aware that `$http.get` does not *return* the result immediately but you have to register an *asynchronous callback*…?

Comment: nope....how should i do that?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: let me check out

Comment: thx man u helped a lot...I ll post the answer...

Comment: @newbie Research before asking questions. Reading documentation is an obvious first step.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to deceze, I came up with this

```
var pathForMW = $http.get(path + 'getNameForMW').then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    pathForMW = response.data;

  }
);
```

that solved my problem....
thx again

Answer (score 1):

This is an async call made with the $http. So a Promise is returned. You need to use .then so you can perform actions on the returned response.

```
$http.get(path + 'getNameForMW').then(function 
                                successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                // you can do something with the response here 
                // like saving it to a variable

}, function errorCallback(response) {
       // called asynchronously if an error occurs
       // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```